# docker run "--cpus" flag confusing

Tags: docker, resources, cpu

I am referring to the `--cpus` flag of [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

The documentation states that the number provided in the flag amounts for the number of CPUs available, which I have found to be untrue.

From the documentation:

```
--cpus=0.000    Number of CPUs. Number is a fractional number. 0.000 means no limit.
```

From the [`limit resources`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu) documentation:

```
--cpus=<value>  Specify how much of the available CPU resources a container can use. For instance, if the host machine has two CPUs and you set --cpus="1.5", the container is guaranteed at most one and a half of the CPUs. This is the equivalent of setting --cpu-period="100000" and --cpu-quota="150000". Available in Docker 1.13 and higher.
```

I have tried the exact above in a docker container with 2 cpus, which resulted in CPU% usage of 100% in docker stats (which should have been 75%). Same result with following declarations:

```
docker run --cpus 1.5 ...
docker run --cpus=1.5 ...
docker run --cpus="1.5" ...
```

When I tried setting a value of 0.5:

```
docker run --cpus 0.5 ...
```

The CPU resources were limited to 50% in `docker stats`, which does not comply with the documentation provided by docker, since the `docker stats` CPU% result should have been 25% (2 CPUs, 0.5 CPU available results in 25% of the CPU capacity)

I am trying to figure out why my perception of the documentation seems to differ from my results, may it be a misinterpretation on my side of the CPU% in `docker stats`, or wrong documentation provided by docker, which in the latter case, I can report back to Docker.

I am running version `Version 18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312)` on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

docker stat command shows calculation multiplied by CPU kernel count, Ex: if your host has 4 cores and any application utilizing 100% CPU then docker stats output like 400%, in your case it's reporting correct values, as you restricted to 0.5 cores means it 1/2 CORE (50% in 1 core)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes sense somehow, but why is the CPU count than never higher than 100% if there are 2 cores available? If I set the value to 1.5, I would expect a CPU% of 150, and it is reporting 100

Comment: Docker stats show utilization report if your docker container utilizing 100% CPU then it show 150%

Comment: @WouterCoebergh if you set the cpu value to 1.5, docker allocate 100% of one core and 50% of an other core in case of need. and not 150% of one core. hope it will make sense to you.